# Get list of all order item for a product

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

I want to get the list of `sales_flat_order_item` for a product.

I tried the following

```
$read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$result = $read->query("SELECT order_item.* FROM sales_flat_order_item AS order_item WHERE order_item.product_id='".$sku."'");
$row = $result->fetch();
```

And this is giving me wrong result. How to get the list of all transactions of a given product id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('product_id', '123');
```